# Automatically clearing the Java Web Start Cache

Tags: java, caching, java-web-start

I have a Java Web Start application. I specify the resource (jars, images, etc) version and change every time there is a new version. Unfortunately sometimes the resources are not always updated when there is a new version.

Is there any automated (possibly include in the application) way of clearing the web start cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in a reliable way.

We have found that making the URL unique for each item helps a lot.  In other words deploy to "foo/20100310/main.jar" etc and update the JNLP file accordingly.